# Handling File upload from html form in python

Tags: python, html, forms, file-upload, cgi

I have a simple html form and backend python handled by cgi-bin. I am trying to upload a file through form and print the contents of that file in my python script. 
My HTML code:

```
<form id = "upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/var/www/cgi-bin/test.py" method="post">
            <div id = "table">
                <table class = "center" border="1" cellpadding="10">
                    <tr><td style="height: 131px">Product Details</td>
                        <td style="height: 131px">Product Name*:&nbsp;<input type="text"  name="product" id="product" size="35" ><br /><br />
                                                  Platform*: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <input type="text"  name="platform" id="platform" size="35" >
                    </td></tr> 
                    <tr><td style="height: 131px">File Upload</td>
                    <td style="height: 131px"><p>Upload Host File: <input type="file" name="hostupload" /></p><br/>
                                                 Upload Test File: <input type="file" name="testupload" /></p>
                    </td></tr> 
                    <tr align="center"><td></td><td><input type = "submit" id="upload" value = "UPLOAD"/>
                   </td></tr>   
                </table>
            </div>
        </form>
```

My python code:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import os
import commands
import cgi, cgitb

print "Content-Type: application/json"
print
form = cgi.FieldStorage()


product = form['product'].value
platform =  form['platform'].value
filedata = form['hostupload']
print product
print platform

if filedata.file:
   print filedata.file.read()
```

The product and platform are printing alright. But if I add the line filedata = form['hostupload'] , I am getting error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 541, in __getitem__, referer:   
[error] [client 10.1.1.212]     raise KeyError, key,
```

But the name "hostupload" is correct in my form. Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: As a side note, if the only reason you're using `filedata.file` is to `read()` the whole thing in at once, it's simpler to just access `filedata.value`. The only reason to go with the extra complexity is if you need to avoid the cost of reading the whole thing into memory.

Comment: Hi, even with, I don't know y I am getting KeyError out here !

Comment: That's why it's a comment that starts with "As a side note", rather than an answer. It's just a way to make your code simpler, not a fix for your problem.

Comment: Meanwhile: Can you first try logging or printing `form.keys()` and post here what you get? That'll help narrow down where the problem is happening.